# .NET Core 2.0 Azure Data Lake and Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

Anyone out there have a workaround for including Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication version v2.3.1 library
with Active Directory in .NET Core 2.0?

There seems to be a version issue with the current Active Directory Library going back to before version 14.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean that the SDK [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) < 3.1.4 is conflicted with [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/2.3.1#) in your case.

According to the [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) Dependencies, we could know that this SDK **requires** the sepicial version [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) (**= 3.13.9**) in the standard platform.

So if  there is a [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) (**not equals 3.13.9**) then should be not compatible. We could get that information from the [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/2.3.1#).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, your response is correct that is the issue that I was having. I have received a response from Microsoft that they will be updating the library with the next month. I also decided to use a different approach to authentication while waiting for the REST update. Appreciate your comment. Cheers Peter

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who has the same issue.